# Estimate correlation coefficient of unknown variable

Tags: statistics, regression, correlation, sampling

Consider variable y depends on variable x and z linearly. I have $100$ sample values of $y$ and corresponding $x$ but don't have any values of $z$. The functional model is

$$y = \alpha_1x + \alpha_2z + \eta $$

Is it possible to estimate $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2 $?

Thanks and regards,

marcella.

Comment: do you know the form of the distribution of $\eta$ and some ense of the distribution of likely values for z? For example, are the errors normally distributed and the z values likely to be lognormal? I ask because if you don't know z then your model is misspecified...you should treat $\alpha_2z$ as a single, *random* effect, which makes your model a mixed-effects model, not a simple regression model.

Comment: Experimental results show that $\eta$ follows standard normal distribution(mean 0), however I don't have any clue about the distribution of z. Thanks

Comment: Do these experimental results also indicate a value for $\sigma$? If you nothing about Z, then you need to fully specify $\eta$ so you can back out an estimate for the distribution of $\alpha_2z$.

Answer (score 0):

No, as you can always absorb $\alpha_2$ into z.